# Javascript E4X: Select a node based on an attribute value

Tags: javascript, e4x

Consider this scenario:

Using Javascript/E4X, in a non-browser usage scenario (a Javascript HL7 integration engine), there is a variable holding an XML snippet that could have multiple repeating nodes.

```
<pets>       
 <pet type="dog">Barney</pet>
 <pet type="cat">Socks</pet>
</pets>
```

Code:

```
var petsXml; // pretend it holds the above xml value
//var cat = petsXml['pet']..... ?
```

**Question**: using E4X, how can you select the correct pet node with the `type` attribute holding the value of string 'cat'?

**Update:**

Some learnings with E4X:

- to select a single/first node by an attribute value: `var dog = petsXml.(@type == "dog");`
- to get a value from one node's specific attribute: `var petType = somePetNode.@type;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var petsXml;
var catList = petsXml.*.(@type == "cat");
```

See "Filters" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/E4X_Tutorial/Descendants_and_Filters) or "parameterized locate" over [here](http://www.1060.org/forum/topic/63/1).

Comment: thanks Pianoman. That worked fine. Although I've successfully implemented the solution as petsXml.(@type == "cat");   Is the asterisk indicating that multiples would be returned, whereas without would be the first match found?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  The `*` should scan all the `<pet>` nodes, and `catList` could very well be an array if there are >1 cats.